# Typescript type checks during development using Webpack and ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin?

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin

I'm new to Typescript and I'm working with the following setup:

- Using `react`, `redux` and `react-redux`
- Bundling with `webpack`
- Type checking with `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin`
- I also use `react-hot-loader`

And I'm getting some weird behavior.

Sometimes I make changes to the types I'm using and `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin` will only show (or not show) type errors after I stop and restart `webpack-dev-server` to compile everything again from scratch.

Is this a normal behavior? Do I need to recompile every time I make changes to the types I'm using?

**For example:**

The plugin is complaining about a `IS_MOBILE` property that is missing from my `LAYOUT` type.

[image]

This is because I was experimenting a new shape for this object.

But you can see that I already removed that property from my `LAYOUT` interface, so that error should not be showing anymore.

[image]

Now I'm going to restart `webpack`:

[image]

You can see from the image above that the error is now gone.

**QUESTION**

Is this the normal behavior for the `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin`? Do I need to recompile everything when I make those kind of changes? Or is it maybe cause because I'm using `react-hot-loader` or some other config I should be using.

**NOTE:** The normal VSCode ts check throughout my opened files is working fine. They always immediately reflect the changes I make to the types I'm using.

**PS:** Those types are declared in `d.ts` files using `declare namespace {...}`

Answer (score 3):

Look like this bug https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/issues/457

You can try to config `ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin`

```
new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
    typescript: {
        build: true,
    },
}),
```

but it's work around and not solution of the problem.